# I can access \\pcname\c$ (or \admin$) from on computer but not several other computers

Tags: network-share, shares

I have a domain computer that I can access the c$ and admin$ from my normal workstation no problem. 
When I try to access those shares from a server, or another PC, logged in as myself or domain admin, I get the "cannot be accessed" error. I've gone through all of the sharing settings and permissions. Has anyone seen this before? Those who have, were you able to fix it?

Thanks,
Travis

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping the machine from the other computer?(ping by name or by IP)
What is the exact error you get?
the two computers are in the same network segment?
if you have connectivity to the computer, perhaps it cant authenticate?
you can try:

```
net use \\[PCNAME]\IPC$ /user:domain\mydomainuser *
```

this will create the RPC authentication with the intended machine (forcing the user to be used) and then you can try again.

Adding more details based on the feedback, 
as both computers are in different segments there is the likehood that a firewall is blocking the communication, you need to ensure the ports are open on both sides (the computer acting as a client and the computer its connected to)
From [KB298804 related to ports used](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/298804):

> Microsoft file sharing SMB: User Datagram Protocol (UDP) ports from
>   135    through 139 and Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) ports from
>   135 through 139.    Direct-hosted SMB traffic without a network basic
>   input/output system (NetBIOS): port 445 (TCP and UPD).

You can try using (use all ports):
    TELNET **IP/pcname** 139
for example (port 96000 is not active)

> C:\Windows\system32>telnet thisisMyServer 96000
>   Connecting To
>   thisisMyServer ...Could not open connection to the host, on port 96000:
>   Connect failed

if it connects successfully you will get a blank screen (you can close pressing **CTRL + ]** )

Comment: I can ping the target machine from any other machine.  


The computers are not on the same segment, but the computer that I can access from is also not on the same segment as the target.


When I try the "net use" command, I get a return of  "System Error 53 has occurred The network path was not found."

The windows error that comes up is 0x80004005 the ever so useful Unspecified error.

Comment: Anyone have any further thoughts? I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: I added more information to the answer I provided.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Other things came up. I'll be testing with your advice soon and will report back.